# Dataframe in pandas, how to stack columns?

Tags: pandas

I want to use multi column indexing but I don't find the solution on the web (I find for multi row indexing but not columns...)

I have data like (and i have diffrent val with different number of years...)

```
id     val_2016    val_2017    val_2018
id01   50           20          20
id02   20           30          40
id03   10           40          10
id04   10           50          50
```

and I want this :

```
id           val
       2016    2017    2018
id01   50       20      20
id02   20       30      40
id03   10       40      10
id04   10       50      50
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try of splitting the columns by '_' and assign to the columns of dataframe

```
df.set_index('id',inplace=True)
df.columns = df.columns.str.split('_',expand=True)
```

Out:

```
    val
    2016    2017    2018
id          
id01    50  20  20
id02    20  30  40
id03    10  40  10
id04    10  50  50
```

Comment: Perfect ! Thanks :)